# Максимальное число файлов которые можно загрузить на сервер

Tags: hdd, unix, php, файлы, linux

Вот такой вот сервер

http://ru.hetzner.com/hosting/produkte_rootserver/ex60

Слышал что у жесткого диска есть ограничение на количество файлов

Можете обьяснить сколько файлов я смогу загрузить на этот сервер

Допустим файлы по 1 кб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество файлов ограничено числом [инодов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), количество их зависит от конкретной файловой системы. В линуксе их количество можно вытащить через df -i, на моем 128gb ssd/ext4 их 2248400 - на 2тб их должно быть **примерно** в 16 раз больше.
Быстрее, чем вы столкнетесь с нехваткой инодов, вы, скорее, столкнетесь с общим падением производительности при листинге файлов или с другими проблемами, видел случай, где ломался сессионный механизм php и сессии пытались жить вечно, забив к чертям все иноды в папке с сессиями (причем стандартными методами их вычистить не удавалось).